# How can I check the validity of a wsdl because i got IllegalAnnotationsException?

Tags: wsdl, cxf, objectfactory

I have generated a java package with the wsdl2java  CXF command.
Now i want to deploy the wsdl to the tomcat server but I got these errors in logs when i start the server

I use opebEjb.

It looks like the wsdl is not valid.
How can i check this?

**Log:**

Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:268)
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:202)
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:397)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1373)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1333)
 ... 30 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:274)
 at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:371)
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:525)
 at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:422)
 at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:190)
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:164)
 at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:100)
 at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:117)
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:168)
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:339)
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:252)
 ... 39 more

**Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 48 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions**

**There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {urn:hl7-org:v3}assignedDevice.**
 this problem is related to the following location:
  at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.santeos.dmp.iheprofiles.hl7.MFMIMT700701UV01AuthorOrPerformer.assignedDevice
  at com.santeos.dmp.iheprofiles.hl7.MFMIMT700701UV01AuthorOrPerformer
  at protected java.util.List com.santeos.dmp.iheprofiles.hl7.PRPAIN201304UV02MFMIMT700701UV01ControlActProcess.authorOrPerformer
  at com.santeos.dmp.iheprofiles.hl7.PRPAIN201304UV02MFMIMT700701UV01ControlActProcess
  at protected com.santeos.dmp.iheprofiles.hl7.PRPAIN201304UV02MFMIMT700701UV01ControlActProcess com.santeos.dmp.iheprofiles.hl7.PRPAIN201304UV02MCCIMT000100UV01Message.controlActProcess
  at com.santeos.dmp.iheprofiles.hl7.PRPAIN201304UV02MCCIMT000100UV01Message

**There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {urn:hl7-org:v3}assignedPerson.**
 this problem is related to the following location:
  at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.santeos.dmp.iheprofiles.hl7.MFMIMT700701UV01AuthorOrPerformer.assignedPerson
  at com.santeos.dmp.iheprofiles.hl7.MFMIMT700701UV01AuthorOrPerformer
  at protected java.util.List com.santeos.dmp.iheprofiles.hl7.PRPAIN201304UV02MFMIMT700701UV01ControlActProcess.authorOrPerformer
  at com.santeos.dmp.iheprofiles.hl7.PRPAIN201304UV02MFMIMT700701UV01ControlActProcess
  at protected com.santeos.dmp.iheprofiles.hl7.PRPAIN201304UV02MFMIMT700701UV01ControlActProcess com.santeos.dmp.iheprofiles.hl7.PRPAIN201304UV02MCCIMT000100UV01Message.controlActProcess
  at com.santeos.dmp.iheprofiles.hl7.PRPAIN201304UV02MCCIMT000100UV01Message

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Can you please share your solution?

Answer (score 1):

As [Julien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/384355/julien) told in a comment above, this issue can be resolved by changing the package name for each wsdl if you are using more than one wsdl. In my case, I had two wsdl's, one downloaded in my work-space along with all the required xsd's and second used using a URL. Both of them pointing to same server. The reason for downloading the first wsdl was two name collision in object factory. Yes, the external bindings didn't worked, simply because the wsdl was total mess.

So, when I was trying to generate sources using wsdltojava, it was failing with "There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl...". I followed [Julien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/384355/julien)'s comments and the issue got resolved. I am not sure if this is the best and cleaner solution, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

What flags are you passing to wsdl2java?

Can you check the generated code for ObjectFactory classes?   Check those to see if any methods are annotated with @XmlElementDecl.

Comment: It was my wsdl2java command:

call wsdl2java -exsh true  -autoNameResolution -p %PACKAGE_BASE%.pdq -p "urn:hl7-org:v3"=%PACKAGE_BASE%.hl7 -d %PROJECT_HOME%\src\main\java\  %WSDL_HOME%\PDQSupplier.wsdl


ObjectFactory had a lot of methods annotated with @XmlElementDecl
Actually, the problem was that the package "hl7" was common to other packages. So, I have changed in the wsdl command the package name from "hl7" to "pdq.hl7" and it works!